# dynamic window focus MVC2

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC2 project, on a view we display a large data set which refreshes every minute with latest data..some specific records are updated every minute in this data set. I want the browser to focus on these specific records..Not sure how to use javascript focus() here dynamically...
any clue?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more detail as to exactly what you are attempting to do.
If you are attempting to focus just ensure each record has a unique identifier then you can focus on individual records.
Alternatively you could simply keep the focus at the top or bottom of wherever you are displaying them.
EDIT:
In that case I would suggest something like the following

```
 var currEle = document.getElementById("Record123");  
 currEle.focus();
```

Comment: yes each record has unique identifier "Id" column. I know how to keep focus on top or bottom but in this case want to keep focus on individual row based on unique id.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose you know how to issue an Ajax call and return either partial view or JSON data and how to use that data on the client afterwards...

You can only *focus* to a point in the document when

1. there's only one change or
2. all changes are summarised together in the same document area

We're also not talking about focusing as in document perspective, but rather about focusing of users attention to document specific content (or part of it).

### First option

You can always use something like `jQuery.scrollintoview()` plugin (link to blog post that describes the plugin [here](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html)) that will scroll document to the record that changed and highlight it using jQuery UI effect highlight. Linked blog post also describes the purpose of visual animated scrolling instead of simple jumping within the document.

### Second option

Put changes at the top and keep your document scrolled at the top when content gets updated. You can blink a few times some icon informing the user of the changed content in the *changes area*.